# Need proof on a model being elementarily equivalent but non-isomorphic

Tags: model-theory

For countable models, elementary equivalence is not equivalent to isomorphism.
For example,  let $\frak{A}= \omega+\Bbb{Z}*\omega$ and $\frak{B}= \omega+\Bbb{Z}*\omega^*$  ($ω^∗$ is the reverse of $ω$). Then $\frak{A}\equiv\frak{B}$ but $\frak{A}\not\cong\frak{B}$ for $\frak{A}$ and $\frak{B}$ are not atomic. (For two countable atomic models if $\frak{A}\equiv\frak{B}$, then $\frak{A}\cong\frak{B}$.)

I am not sure how to prove $\frak{A}\equiv\frak{B}$ exactly even though I know Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game can do it. Also, I am not sure how to prove they are not atomic.

*Note:* This question has been posted on the Math StackExchange website, but can not get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the models are not isomorphic assume an isomorphism $f:\frak{A}\to\frak{B}$, take $(a_n)_{n\in\omega}$ be an increasing sequence such $a_i,a_j$ are from a different copy of $\Bbb Z$ for each $i\ne j$.

Now look at $f(a_i),f(a_j)$. If they are from the same copy of $\Bbb Z$ then there exists some natural number $n$ that is their difference, and so there is a first order formula that represent this ("There exists exactly $n-1$ different elements that are between $f(a_i)$ and $f(a_j)$), because $f$ is an isomorphism it would imply that there is exactly $n-1$ elements between $a_i,a_j$ which is a contradiction.

Now for each $a_i$ let $b_i$ be the unique $k\in\omega^*$ such that $f(a_i)∈{\Bbb Z}×\{k\}$, this result with $(b_i)_{i\in\omega}$ being an increasing sequence in $ω^*$, contradiction.

---

To see that they are elementary equivalent we want to look at the EF game of length $n$, $G_n(\frak A,B)$.

When the Spoiler pick an element from $ω$ of one of the structures, the Duplicator will choose the same element from $\omega$ in the other one.

Next if the Spoiler choose an element not from $\frak A\setminus\omega$, then the Duplicator will choose any element from ${\Bbb Z}×\{-n^n\}$ in $\frak B$, and dually if the Spoiler choose from $\frak B\setminus\omega$.

Next if the Spoiler chooses an element that is a finite distance from a chosen element, the Duplicator will just duplicate this distance with the corresponded element in the other model.

If the Spoiler chooses a new $\Bbb Z$, the Duplicator will duplicate the $\Bbb Z$ but will cap the distance between the index of the chosen $\Bbb Z$ to the index of existing chosen indexes to have $k^k$ where $k$ is the number of steps left to the game. This will leave enough room to full out any kind of structure the Spoiler will try to create.

---

To see that they are not atomic, let for each natural $n$ $φ_n(x)$ be "$x$ is at least $n$" and let $τ(x)$ be the partial type consistent of all $\phi_n$. Note that for each $a\in\frak A$ we have $a\notin ω⇔τ(a)$, in particular $τ⊆\operatorname{tp}(a)$.

Now let $ψ(x)$ be any formula (that does not contain $z\ne z$ for some variable $z$), $ψ(x)$ can only describe what kind of finite linear orders exists/don't exists bellow $x$ and what kind of finite linear orders above $x$ and the distance of those orders from $x$ *if it is finite* and their distance from $0$ *if it is finite*

We don't care about what happens above $x$ because the end segment of $a$ and the end segment of $b$ are isomorphic for all $a,b$.

Now take some $a\notin ω$ and assume that $\operatorname{tp}(a)$ is isolated by $ψ(x)$. Note that any finite linear order exists bellow $a$, in particular $ψ(x)$ only describe what kind of orders **do** exists bellow $x$ and the distance of those orders if it is finite.

Take a natural number $m$ that is bigger than the sum of the length of the orders that $ψ$ describe plus the distance from $x$ of those orders plus the distance from $0$ of those orders, and any element $b∈ω\setminus m$ will satisfy $ψ$, in particular $ψ(x)\;\not\!\!\!\implies φ_b(x)$ and hence does not isolate $\operatorname{tp}(a)$

Comment: @user103 Try to show that there is no single formula $φ(x)$ such that $φ(x)⇒x\notin ω$, now take $a\in {\frak A}\setminus\omega$, show that if $\operatorname{tp}(a)$ is isolated by $ψ(x)$ then $ψ(x)⇒x\notin\omega$, and reach a contradiction (and similarly for $\frak B$)

Comment: @user103 I wrote one